# Is there a function that can convert ACAccountTypeIdentifier to SLServiceType?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk

I saw that those are similar

```
SOCIAL_EXTERN NSString *const SLServiceTypeTwitter NS_AVAILABLE(10_8, 6_0);
SOCIAL_EXTERN NSString *const SLServiceTypeFacebook NS_AVAILABLE(10_8, 6_0);
SOCIAL_EXTERN NSString *const SLServiceTypeSinaWeibo NS_AVAILABLE(10_8, 6_0);
SOCIAL_EXTERN NSString *const SLServiceTypeTencentWeibo NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 7_0);
SOCIAL_EXTERN NSString *const SLServiceTypeLinkedIn NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, NA);

ACCOUNTS_EXTERN NSString * const ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter NS_AVAILABLE(NA, 5_0);
ACCOUNTS_EXTERN NSString * const ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook NS_AVAILABLE(NA, 6_0);
ACCOUNTS_EXTERN NSString * const ACAccountTypeIdentifierSinaWeibo NS_AVAILABLE(NA, 6_0);
ACCOUNTS_EXTERN NSString * const ACAccountTypeIdentifierTencentWeibo NS_AVAILABLE(NA, 7_0);
ACCOUNTS_EXTERN NSString * const ACAccountTypeIdentifierLinkedIn NS_AVAILABLE(NA, NA);
```

Why keep track of both? Why 2 sets of different constants? Is there a function that can convert one to another or should I make them myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing more details about what you're trying to do, needing to convert between the two sets of constants jumps out at me as being kind of the wrong thing to do.

Social.framework and Accounts.framework are separate frameworks that serve different purposes -- you can use one without the other.

Comment: One could build a Social framework that manages both requesting permissions to accounts and posting to those accounts. A function like this would make sense in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making these functions:

```
-(NSString *) strAccountTypeIdentifier
{
    if (self.bglm==BGLoginModeTwitter)
    {
        return ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter;
    }
    else if(self.bglm==BGLoginModeFacebook)
    {
        return ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook;
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}
-(NSString *) strSLServiceType
{
    if (self.bglm==BGLoginModeTwitter)
    {
        return SLServiceTypeTwitter;
    }
    else if(self.bglm==BGLoginModeFacebook)
    {
        return SLServiceTypeFacebook;
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}

-(ACAccountType *) ACAccounts
{
    NSAssert(self.ACAstore, @"ACAStore must not be empty by this time");
    return [self.ACAstore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:self.strAccountTypeIdentifier];
}

-(NSString *) strAccountName{
    if (self.bglm==BGLoginModeTwitter)
    {
        return @"Twitter";
    }
    else if(self.bglm==BGLoginModeFacebook)
    {
        return @"Facebook";
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Now, I need only one enum of type BGLoginMode and that is it. I can get the rest easily by calling those functions.